# Start ActivityforResult showing Depriciated

Tags: java, android

Code to Run startActivityForResult showing error  :

`Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK); intent.setType("image/*"); startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_PICKER);`

onActivity Result Error :

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICKER && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            if (data != null) {

                photoUri = data.getData();

                updateBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

        }

    }
```

[Want to add onActivityResult but not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPa1w.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPa1w.jpg)

Comment: post your error and explain your exact problem

Comment: @Erfan I've added the image where I am getting errors please check !!

Comment: you should put onActivityResult outside onCreate method

Comment: Could you just copy & paste the edited code please

Answer (score 0):

This method appears deprecated when you upgrade the Activity library, and now you have to use [`registerForActivityResult()`](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result).

Create a `ActivityResultLauncher`

```
ActivityResultLauncher<String> imagePickerResult = registerForActivityResult(new GetContent(),
    new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(Uri uri) {
            // Do what you need with that Uri
        }
});
```

Then instead of `startActivityForResult` use `launch`

```
imagePickerResult.launch("image/*");
```

Then in your `imagePickerResult` will fire when user select an image.

Note that in your case you can use a default [`Activity Result Contract`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts) but in case you would need a custom contract you would have to create it by your own, here's an example of how it works.

```
public class PickRingtone extends ActivityResultContract<Integer, Uri> {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Intent createIntent(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Integer ringtoneType) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, ringtoneType.intValue());
        return intent;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri parseResult(int resultCode, @Nullable Intent result) {
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK || result == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return result.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
    }
}
```